# Silverlight 4 + Prism + WCF: Storing user information globally

Tags: silverlight, wcf, prism

I've set up a Silverlight 4 Application with PRISM 4. During startup I'd like to get the Active Directory User GUID of the currently logged on User and want to make it accessible for the entire application. What's the best practice for achieving this? Getting the User GUID itself is no problem for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There many ways, i'd suggest you to create a service interface with properties for your settings, for example:

```
public interface ISettingsService
{
    Guid ActiveDirectoryGuid { get; }

    // Other settings
}
```

and have Prism to inyect a singleton instance of a class that implement the interface into whatever place where you need the setting.

Comment: Not yet sure how I'd combine this with the WCF service, since all the data access (SQL or Directory Service) goes through WCF...

Comment: @Malkier: you didn't explain what WCF has to do with this scenario. Do you need this data behind the WCF service during a call as well as on the client? If so you'd want to authenticate with the service with Windows Authentication to flow the user information across so the same guid can be retrieved behind the service.

Comment: I already managed to use windows authentication on the silverlight app, so that I get the name of the currently logged on user. Via OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name in WCF, I can get the current User of the Silverlight App. The plan was to generate the UserGUID out of this information in the service and pass the UserGUID back to Silverlight.

Comment: @Malkier: ok, so if you create the application service Rafa suggests and have it retrieve that info via a WCF call once, you should be good.  Do you need a full sample of this?

Comment: I think I'm fine with this for now, will try this ASAP, thank you

Comment: Now I got it plus I learned something about Imports/Exports in MEF. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too worried about client side security then you can store the the information in the [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and pass it to WCF or use it in silverlight

If you want the information accessible anywhere in your WCF service. Then i suggest using a MembershipProvider that authenticates the user against the Active directory store, then you can access it via the [OperationContext](http://operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity)